# Register type as InstancePerRequest with Exception(s)

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, dependency-injection, autofac, autofac-configuration

I am using [AutoFac](https://autofac.org/) in my Web API application (*using the latest versions available as of time this question was posted*). One of my service dependencies is an `AuditService` which uses an instance of by `DbContext` type (*let's call it `MyDbContext` for now*). Most of my services and the `MyDbContext` type are all registered using [InstancePerRequest](http://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/lifetime/instance-scope.html#instance-per-request). For my `AuditService` I want to make an exception, I always want to inject an owned (*new*) instance of my `MyDbContext`.

**Question**: Using [AutoFac](https://autofac.org/) registrations, how do I register my `AuditService` in such a way that it always gets an owned (new) instance of `MyDbContext`?

---

What *could* work:

- I could hard code the creation of `MyDbContext` in the constructor of `AuditService` thus circumventing AutoFac all together.
- I could use [PropertyInjection or MethodInjection](http://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/register/prop-method-injection.html) and provide a new instance of `MyDbContext` in the Life Time event [OnActivating](http://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/lifetime/events.html?highlight=OnActivating)
- I could define a second interface on `MyDbContext` and provide a second registration and use `InstancePerOwned`.

Do I have to pick one of these above options (*if so I would lean towards 3*) or am I missing something simple? Is there a way to define what I want in my registration code?

---

```
// registration called in web api startup code
public void RegisterAutofac(ContainerBuilder builder)
{
    builder.RegisterType<MyDbContext>()
        .As<IMyDbContext>()
        .InstancePerRequest();

    builder.RegisterType<BusinessService>()
        .As<IBusinessService>()
        .InstancePerRequest();

    builder.RegisterType<AuditService>()
        .As<IAuditService>()
        .InstancePerRequest();
}


public class AuditService
{
    // expects an isolated instance on this request
    private readonly IMyDbContext _dbContext;
    public AuditService(IMyDbContext dbContext)
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
    }
}

public class BusinessService
{
    // expect a shared IMyDbContext instance across the request
    private readonly IMyDbContext _dbContext;
    public BusinessService(IMyDbContext dbContext)
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
    }
}
```

---

### Solution Attempts with InstancePerOwned

This causes an exception

```
builder.RegisterType<MyDbContext>()
    .As<IMyDbContext>()
    .InstancePerRequest()
    .InstancePerOwned<AuditService>();
```

> Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException: "No scope with a tag matching 'AuditService' is visible from the scope in which the instance was requested. If you see this during execution of a web application, it generally indicates that a component registered as per-HTTP request is being requested by a SingleInstance() component (or a similar scenario). Under the web integration always request dependencies from the dependency resolver or the request lifetime scope, never from the container itself.
>
> ```
> at Autofac.Core.Lifetime.MatchingScopeLifetime.FindScope(ISharingLifetimeScope mostNestedVisibleScope)
> at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup..ctor(IComponentRegistration registration, IResolveOperation context, ISharingLifetimeScope mostNestedVisibleScope, IEnumerable`1 parameter
> ```

---

I tried reversing the order of `InstancePerOwned` and `InstancePerRequest` calls but this seems to have no effect, the same `MyDbContext` instance is reused for both `BusinessService` and `AuditService` instances in the same request. This was tested with `object.ReferenceEquals` from in an `ApiController` and passed in both instance's `_dbContext` fields.

```
builder.RegisterType<MyDbContext>()
    .As<IMyDbContext>()
    .InstancePerOwned<AuditService>()
    .InstancePerRequest();
```

Comment: How can you want `persist audit records independent from business logic done` but still have a dependency on `(new) instance of MyDbContext when it is created`?  Why would it not take an `IAuditDbContext` of which you could the register `MyDbContext` as `IAuditDbContext` with a different lifetime scope.

Comment: @ErikPhilips - let me rephrase those 2 lines so my intent is clear. In a nut shell, I just want `AuditService` to always get a new instance of `MyDContext` while `BusinessService` (and any subsequent services also registered this way) will always get a "shared" instance of `MyDbContext`.

Comment: @ErikPhilips - Yes, I believe I could do that (*I listed it as the 3rd bullet under "What could work:"*). I thought there was a way I could do this without have to extend the `IMyDbContext` interface for this. Perhaps I am wrong but I do not know every in/out of AutoFac so I figured I would ask before I jump to that conclusion.

Comment: I wouldn't derive from `IMyDbContext`, otherwise you're creating a dependency for no real reason.

Answer (score 1):

Try switching from `InstancePerRequest` to `InstancePerLifetimeScope`. In most apps this generally behaves the same [and is the way to share registrations across apps that both do and don't have per-request semantics](http://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq/per-request-scope.html) anyway. (Which is to say, this is pretty common.)

Once you have `InstancePerLifetimeScope` on your context object, you can [use `Owned<T>` in your `AuditService` constructor](http://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/resolve/relationships.html#controlled-lifetime-owned-b) to get a fresh copy.

So...

```
builder.RegisterType<MyDbContext>()
    .As<IMyDbContext>()
    .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

then...

```
public AuditService(Owned<IMyDbContext> dbContext)
```

Note your `AuditService` will be responsible for disposing of the `dbContext` when it's done, so you'll have to handle that manually (that's part of using `Owned<T>`). But if you've already got some one-off stuff going on, that shouldn't be a big deal.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What I will probably end up doing is registering the `MyDbContext` a second time with a different interface and marking the registration as `InstancePerOwned`. That way I do not have to "pollute" my service types with AutoFac specific registration code / types.